# Hide matplot annotation if value is 0

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908800/annotate-values-for-stacked-horizontal-bar-in-pandas).

Take the example below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = {'group 1': [0, 2, 5, 7, 0, 5, 0],
     'group 2': [0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 6, 2],
     'group 3': [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 8, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(10,12))

for p in ax.patches:
    left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds
    ax.annotate(str(width), xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), 
                ha='center', va='center', size = 12)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, -0.15), loc=3, prop={'size': 14}, frameon=False)
```

You can see how the annotations (when the value is 0) makes the graph look pretty bad.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how the annotations for 0 values could be removed or hidden while retaining the annotations for the non-zero values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you simply need to add an `if` statement in the loop

```
for p in ax.patches:
    left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds
    ax.annotate(str(width), xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), 
                ha='center', va='center', size = 12)
```

to filter out instances where `width == 0.0`, i.e.

```
for p in ax.patches:
    left, bottom, width, height = p.get_bbox().bounds
    if width != 0.0:
        ax.annotate(str(width), xy=(left+width/2, bottom+height/2), 
                    ha='center', va='center', size = 12)
```

This will give you

[image: Plot with annotations filtered (size adjusted from OP code)]